# DNN 6.2 URL hacked

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I am running one of my client's websites on DotNetNuke 6.2. Yesterday I noticed that the menu links for the website appear to have been hacked.

So when I click on a link which is supposed to go to: www.wossname.com/search.aspx
It instead takes me to: http://www.wossname.comlley.com.auomnern.edumd400b40cn/Search.aspx

So basically I think that someone has hacked the URL generation bit of DNN and added some malicious code to our DNN installation. I am aware that I should upgrade to the latest version of DNN but I am looking for a short term fix to keep the site running in the interim.

Is their any solution to this?

Comment: Clean the site, restore from backup. This is not a programming issue so it's off-topic here.

Comment: Be sure to turn off auto generate portal aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about asking an off topic question. I was under the impression that it would be a scripting issue and would be related to code. Anyway I just happened to check the database and noticed that multiple aliases are being created. So if you are having a similar problem simply delete those aliases and you should get the site running in the interim. Of course do update your version of DNN ASAP!